# karate.robot can be accessed in .java or js files/ Can java or Js code call feature files?

Tags: karate

I had the following questions:

1. I want to use Karate. robot in Java or Js files, is there a way to use it?  can the robot interface be extended?
2. Calling a feature file from Java code is possible?

TIA.

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information in order to get an answer.  Karate robot is language neutral and can be called from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes to both questions.

1. [`karate-robot`](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-robot) is a Maven artifact. And here is an [example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/karate-robot/src/test/java/robot/core/ChromeJavaRunner.java). Sorry JS is not an option. Maybe yes, because of something called "Graal", but not officially supported, and you are welcome to experiment.
2. You can call a feature file from Java: https://github.com/intuit/karate#invoking-feature-files-using-the-java-api